# Как отправить фото ботом вк на пхп?

Tags: php, api, вконтакте

Отправляю так

```
$attachment = 'photo-175583814_457239455';
$vk->sendMessage($peer_id, $attachment);
```

Проблема в том, что бот шлет сам этот текст, а не фото

Answer (score 0):

Бот и должен слать текст. Потому что в переменной он и содержится.
https://vk.com/dev/photos

Answer (score 0):

Так у вас `sendMessage`, напишите `sendImage`.